# Fast removal of only zero columns in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, performance

Using:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,3,(100000,5000)))

df = df.loc[:, (df != 0).any(axis=0)]
```

to get rid of columns containing only zeros is way too slow for a very large (1000000x2000) dataframe. Any suggestions how to speed this up?

Thanks

Comment: can you show a sample of your dataframe? see [mcve] and [ask]

Comment: sure i added a sample df albeit i dont think it makes any difference

Comment: if all integers might be quicker to sum across your axis `df.loc[:,df.sum(0).gt(0)]`

Comment: now i see why you were asking :) thanks for this hint. I will give it a try quickly

Comment: Maybe replace 0 with nan and dropna with how = all ? I expect the sum agg to b significantly better tho

Comment: Do you have any a priori idea about the percentage of zeros in your dataframe and or number of columns that are going to be dropped?

Comment: @Ben.T yes i would say >90% zeros

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a much faster way to implement that using **Numba**.

Indeed, most of the Numpy implementation will create *huge temporary arrays* that are slow to fill and read. Moreover, Numpy will *iterate over the full dataframe* while this is often not needed (at least in your example). The point is that you can very quickly know if you need to keep a column by just iteratively check column values and **early stop the computation of the current column if there is any 0** (typically at the beginning). Moreover, **there is no need to always copy the entire dataframe** (using about 1.9 GiB of memory): when all the columns are kept. Finally, you can perform the computation in **parallel**.

However, there are performance-critical low-level catches. First, Numba cannot deal with Pandas dataframes, but the conversion to a Numpy array is almost free using `df.values` (the same thing applies for the creation of a new dataframe). Moreover, regarding the **memory layout** of the array, it could be better to iterate either over the lines or over the columns in the innermost loop.

[image: Memory layout]

This layout can be fetched by checking the *strides* of the input dataframe Numpy array.

Note that the example use a row-major dataframe due to the (unusual) Numpy random initialization, but most dataframes tend to be column major.

Here is an optimized implementation:

```py
import numba as nb

@nb.njit('int_[:,:](int_[:,:])', parallel=True)
def filterNullColumns(dfValues):
    n, m = dfValues.shape
    s0, s1 = dfValues.strides
    columnMajor = s0 < s1
    toKeep = np.full(m, False, dtype=np.bool_)

    # Find the columns to keep
    # Only-optimized for column-major dataframes (quite complex otherwise)
    for colId in nb.prange(m):
        for rowId in range(n):
            if dfValues[rowId, colId] != 0:
                toKeep[colId] = True
                break

    # Optimization: no columns are discarded
    if np.all(toKeep):
        return dfValues

    # Create a new dataframe
    newColCount = np.sum(toKeep)
    res = np.empty((n,newColCount), dtype=dfValues.dtype)
    if columnMajor:
        newColId = 0
        for colId in nb.prange(m):
            if toKeep[colId]:
                for rowId in range(n):
                    res[rowId, newColId] = dfValues[rowId, colId]
                newColId += 1
    else:
        for rowId in nb.prange(n):
            newColId = 0
            for colId in range(m):
                res[rowId, newColId] = dfValues[rowId, colId]
                newColId += toKeep[colId]
    return res

result = pd.DataFrame(filterNullColumns(df.values))
```

Here are the result on my 6-core machine:

```
Reference:           1094 ms
Valdi_Bo answer:     1262 ms
This implementation:    0.056 ms  (300 ms with discarded columns)
```

This, the implementation is about **20 000 times faster** than the reference implementation on the *provided example* (no discarded column) and **4.2 times faster** on more *pathological cases* (only one column discarded).

If you want to reach even faster performance, then you can perform the computation **in-place** (*dangerous*, especially due to Pandas) or use **smaller datatypes** (like `np.uint8` or `np.int16`) since the computation is mainly *memory-bound*.

Comment: I'm surprised by only 4.2 times faster in case a column to discard. I implemented the first part `# Find the columns to keep`  on my side and find really good performance, I wonder if the part `# Create a new dataframe` is not the problem here, would `return dfValues[:, toKeep]` instead a faster solution? to be fair, if you discard more than 1 column, then the gain should increase, no?

Comment: I think to make a fair comparison, we should separate cases 1) nothing to remove, 2) something to remove. Valdi_Bo and reference versions are silently assuming that there is always something to remove. Dummy example will never in our lives produce 2000/5000 of only zeros and whole checking is meaningless :)

Comment: I tested this with a dataframe containing zero-only columns and it is still ~3k times faster than my inital solution!  Thanks for this awesome code snippet

Answer (score 3):

*Numpy* is known to operate substantially faster than *Pandas*.

So to discover which columns contain only zeroes use:

```
np.all(np.equal(df.values, 0), axis=0)
```

But your task is to drop these columns in a **DataFrame**,
as I suppose, keeping source column names.

So the actual drop must be performed on the source Dataframe,
using *loc* and negated result of the above check.

Something like:

```
df = df.loc[:, ~np.all(np.equal(df.values, 0), axis=0)]
```

Comment: I tested this answer and to my surprise it did not give a speedup for the above example.